# How do physicists determine where to place the world or inertial frame when describing the equation of motion of an object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

[image]

For example, I have a pendulum as shown in the diagram above. I would like to write down its equation of motion. To do this, I must define a world frame (or inertial frame, or origin).

But this is where I am stuck. I do not understand the thought process behind where I should place it.

After some Googling, I found that, based on an unknown mechanism, phyiscists like to place the world frame for this object at the tip of the pendulum at the downward position.

In doing so, the following equation makes sense:

$$P = mg\ell (1-\cos(\theta))$$

where $P$ is the potential energy, $\theta$ is the angle that the massless pendulum shaft makes with the vertical line, $\ell$ is the length of the pendulum shaft, $\ell (1-\cos(\theta))$ is then the height of the pendulum from the tip of the pendulum to the $x$-axis of the world frame.

But why? Can the world frame be arbitrarily assigned anywhere on the 2D plane? For example, if we look at the above diagram, we see that the pendulum is suspended a distance away from the platform. So why not place my world frame so that it is aligned with the platform?

[image]

This question is for pendulum in particular, but I am also wondering about how to place the world frame for other objects, for example, a pendulum on a cart, a disc rolling down a slope, a vehicle, etc.

I would appreciate if someone can shed some insight!

Comment: We usually pick the position where, if everything simply stops moving and would stay still, that location to be the origin. Note that you are saying to pick where the origin is; strictly speaking, the location of the origin does not matter, and we are free to pick whatever origin is most convenient and introduces the least of annoying terms to keep track of. The choice of origin has nothing to do with choosing inertial frame, which is about "constant velocity".

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I don't quite get the distinction between the origin and "world/inertial frame". It seems that in my textbook, the two are equal. For example, if a robot is moving on a plane, then there is a world frame, and then there is a body frame. The position and orientation of the robot in its body frame is relative to the world frame.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that comes with experience. I wouldn't say there is a step-by-step process to identifying how you will define the frame of reference in which you will carry out the calculation. The fact is: physics is independent of the frame of reference, so you can pick whichever one you prefer. Typically, we will look for the frame of reference that simplifies the equations the most by exploiting symmetries and other properties. In the case of the pendulum, that is a good choice of coordinates because it ends up describing the pendulum solely in terms of the angle $\theta$. In other situations, we will also look to reduce the number of variables as much as possible and try to align our coordinates with the symmetries of the problem. But I'd say that managing to do this efficiently is something that comes with experience.